# How to delete spaces in a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

here is an exemple of code :

```
private JFormattedTextField jftf2 = new JFormattedTextField();
try{
    MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("###-####");
    mask.install(jftf2);
}catch(ParseException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

when I execute it, it shows 3 spaces then '-' then 4 spaces,i want to know how not to have those spaces, a simple empty textfield that receives no more than the characters i write. i know that there is a method `mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');`  that changes the space to another character but I just want to delete it, not to change it.

another problem is while changing the text, for exemple let's take the same mask `###-####` the string `111-1234` is valid in  that mask but when i delete the 3 for exemple it shows `111-12 4` instead of `111-124` ,  it adds a space, how to resolve that ?

thanx

Comment: So maybe you need just give up the `MaskFormatter` and add a key press event, and for each key press check the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not quite clear what you want as it is a bit strange to use a `MaskFormatter` and complain that it behaves like a `MaskFormatter`. But maybe you wish to do something like this:

```
JFormattedTextField jftf2 = new JFormattedTextField();
final InternationalFormatter fmt=new InternationalFormatter(
  new MessageFormat("{0,number,000}-{1,number,0000}"));
jftf2.setFormatterFactory(new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory() {
  public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter
                                         getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
    return fmt;
  }
});
jftf2.setValue(new Object[]{111,1234});
```

With this format the `value` property of the `JFormattedTextField` will be expressed as an object array of length `2` containing two numbers. The `000` and `0000` in the format specifier above tell it to format the numbers with leading zeros by default (though the user does not need to input them to make a valid input). But you can change it to `0` for compact numbers.